# KDE Marble doesn't show the Legend

Tags: kde, kde-apps

I use Ubuntu Studio 20.04.

The geographic app *KDE Marble* is a very powerful map viewer.

But, I found a bug since I upgraded my system from 19.10 to 20.04 (but, I'm not absolutely sure if this bug is directly related with the upgrading itself).

The bug is about the *Legend* panel: I cannot to see something there.

I'd expect to see all the map symbols in that panel, but... Nothing is shown.

What's wrong here?

How could I work around this?

Comment: It doesn't seem related to the 19.10 > 20.04 upgrade. Legends are missing in a clean install of Kubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Oh! I see. What can we do about this? ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the packagers had decided not (or failed) to link against the QtWebEngine. In this case some of Marble's functionality is not provided.